# Who talks through the Cave/alethiometer?

Tags: his-dark-materials

In the world of *His Dark Material*, it is known that uncountable angels exist. If the Cave/alethiometer can talk to these beings, then which one of them "picks up the call"? Is it ever shown in the books which one of them replies to Lyra and Mary Malone?

Comment: What makes you think it's an angel replying?

Comment: I always assumed it's answers magically came from the device itself. Is there a reason in the books or movies to think otherwise?

Comment: @MikeC: The latter two books are quite explicit about that. Read the upvoted answer.

Comment: I have no quotes to back it up, but Dust as a whole (what someone might identify as the the true God) communicates. Individual angels are separate manifestations of Dust with their own identity and free will. So while Dust is angels (or more specifically, angels are Dust), it's not any specific angel replying.

Comment: @AakashM It was the reply that the cave gave to Malone. Malone: what are you? Cave: Angels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the world of His Dark Material, it is known that uncountable angels exist. If the Cave/alethiometer can talk to these beings, then which one of them "picks up the call"?

While we meet a number of *named* angels in these books, the force or forces that are  conversed with by the Cave (the device in our universe) and the alethiometer (the device in Lyra's) don't appear to be exactly the same kind of being.

We find out in chapter 4 'Trepanning' of *The Subtle Knife*, when Lyra and Dr Malone are conversing, that the same powers controlling the alethiometer are those controlling the Cave; and then in chapter 12 'Screen Language', we get this:

> [Malone is alone in the lab with the Cave, which has been hooked up to
> a text display following Lyra's instructions, and is shocked to see
> words appearing in reply to her typing]
>
> It took several moments for her to calm down enough to try agian. When
> she did, the answers lashed themselves across the right of the screen
> almost before she had finished
>
> ```
> Are you Shadows?
>     Yes.
> Are you the same as Lyra's Dust?
>     Yes.
> And is that dark matter?
>     Yes.
> Dark matter is conscious?
>     Evidently.
> ```
>
> [Later]
>
> ```
> The mind that is answering these questions isn't human, is it?
>     No. But humans have always known us.
> Us? There's more than one of you?
>     Uncountable billions.
> But what are you?
>     Angels.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Angels are creatures of Shadow-matter? Of Dust?
>     Structures. Complexifications. Yes.
> ```

So "structures. complexifications" of Dust are behind the devices' movements - but it seems that these are not exactly the same kind of beings as the named angels we see, such as Baruch, Balthamos, and Metatron himself - those are all localised in space and move around the physical world(s).

Comment: So even though what answers the questions is not the same as the named angels, it considers itself as an angel?

Comment: In the [Later] bit I elided, Mary remembers her Catholic thoelogy: 'angel' refers to the office, not the nature. 'Angel' comes to us from the Greek 'angelos', which before it had its religious meaning simply meant 'messenger' or 'announcer'.